# Does prefab have a different instance id then GameObject or Transform ? Getting exception when trying to get the InstanceID

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public void Load()
        {
            Dictionary<int, Transform> instanceIdToObject = objectsToSave
                .ToDictionary(o => o.gameObject.GetInstanceID(), o => o);
            var saveString = SaveSystem.Load();
            if (saveString != null)
            {
                SaveGame saveGame = JsonUtility.FromJson<SaveGame>(saveString);
                foreach (var saveObject in saveGame.saveObjects)
                {
                    List<KeyToValue> loadedComponents = saveObject.componentsState;
                    var objectToSetState = instanceIdToObject[saveObject.gameObjectInstanceID];
    
                    objectToSetState.position = saveObject.transformSaver.position;
                    objectToSetState.rotation = saveObject.transformSaver.rotation;
                    objectToSetState.localScale = saveObject.transformSaver.scaling;
    
                    var y = objectToSetState.GetComponents<Component>();
                    var z = y.Where(component => component is IStateQuery).ToList();
                    Dictionary<string, IStateQuery> zz = z.ToDictionary(sq => (sq as IStateQuery).UniqueId.ToString(), sq => sq as IStateQuery);
    
                    foreach (KeyToValue keyvalue in loadedComponents)
                    {
                        zz[keyvalue.Key].SetState(keyvalue.Value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

When using a break point on the line :

```
var objectToSetState = instanceIdToObject[saveObject.gameObjectInstanceID];
```

The gameObjectInstanceID value is the one I saved before in the saved file : 743184

On the same line the value of instanceIdToObject is : 1096884
And when I'm looking on the prefab in the editor this ID don't belong to it's gameobject or transform.

The InstanceID I see also in the Inspecotor of the porefab :

[image: Not the right ID]

The the prefab name is the name in the instanceIdToObject.
And this is the prefab instance id for the gameobject and transform in the inspector :

[image: The id's of the gameobject and transform of the prefab]

I'm not sure what and where from is this id 1096884.
In the file on the hard disk the ID number is the same as the ID in the gameObjectInstanceID.
But the ID 1096884 just not exist.

That is why I also getting exception on this line since the id is not exist in the Dictionary.

KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.

Comment: I created a small script I ran over all the objects in the Hierarchy and got all the objects instanceid and all the objects transforms instanceid and all the objects compoments instance id and there is no any number id that is even close to the 1096884.

Comment: Every unity object has its own unique instance ID.

Comment: @shingo I know and it's not answering for my question what is this 1096884.

Comment: Ok, I found the problem but not a solution.  The problem is when I'm loading a saved game first I'm clicking the escape key to go back to the main menu scene then when clicking the loading button it's loading again the Game scene and then it's giving the objects a new instance id's but they are not the same as in the saved file. How can I solve it ?

Comment: You‘d better think about the save system again. Usually objects are saved by its type. For example there are dogs and cats in the scene, every dog in the dog collection is identical, so it can be loaded by any saved data has the type dog.

Comment: Use something like an instance ID to map objects between scenes is not necessary, except every object is unique. If so you can create an unique ID for each one by hand.